# closing mutex handle of created process

Tags: c++, mutex, handle

I am trying to close the handle of a process that I am creating. I start with creating it like this:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFOA si = {sizeof(si)};
char szAppPath[MAX_PATH] = "";

GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, szAppPath, MAX_PATH);
std::string strAppDirectory = szAppPath;
strAppDirectory = strAppDirectory.substr(0, strAppDirectory.rfind("\\")) + "\\game.exe";

int creation = CreateProcessA(strAppDirectory.c_str(), NULL,
    NULL, NULL, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL,
                strAppDirectory.substr(0, strAppDirectory.rfind("\\")).c_str(),
                &si, &pi);
```

I then check if the process is running like this:

```
if (creation != 0 && IsProcessRunning(pi.dwProcessId))
{
    cout << "created process is running\n";
    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
    WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    cout << pi.dwProcessId << "\n";

    SystemHandle* handle = SystemHandle::EnumerateProcessHandles(pi.dwProcessId);

    cout << handle << "\n\n";

    if (handle != NULL)
    {
        NTSTATUS cExecution = handle->Close(true);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(cExecution))
        {
            cout << "success\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "failure\n";
        }
    }

    free(&handle);
    handle = NULL;
}
```

On other computers we get errors:

> First-chance exception at 0x00407A54 in game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00003102.

and

> Unhandled exception at 0x00407A54 in game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00003102.

On my machine, this works every time but on others they often get a crash. I can reproduce this crash if I comment out `WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);` which makes me think: is it because they have slower computers?

I do a break when the crash happens and it tells me row 30 in this gist (SystemHandle.cpp) are causing these problems:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6a8cfb1fd00bd9525818

Comment: I assume it was line 30 before you added all the `cout` lines to that code? To be honest I don't understand what that code is trying to achieve, but calling `free()` on kernel handles is definitely wrong. You're also using it in the code above to free the `SystemHandle`, which was created with `new`. `free()` is not a general purpose "delete something" function that you can just pass anything you like to.

Comment: No, it's the `cout` that cause the crash. Line 31 does aswell if it would come first. I am trying to close a mutex handle associated with game.exe which is called `"\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\GameMutex"`.